# Node/Vue: Create app from Node hosted index file or bypass?

Tags: node.js, vue.js

If I want to create a Node and Vue app, what is the proper way to hook them up together.
Correct me I am wrong but the way I see it is I have two options:

**1)** inside Node, I can render an index file and from within the index file, inject Vue

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/index.html'));
});
```

so then `localhost:3000/` would render the index file that has view injected in it and then use Vue router from there to navigate.

**2)**  2nd option would be to access Vue directly and just use Node as an api so I would access it via `localhost:8080/`

---

does this sound correct and are there advantages of one way over another?

Comment: there is problems with both. IMO use nuxt with serverside rendering by adding nuxt middleware to express, this way you can have both API, frontend and prepopulated stores with nuxtServerInit and all that good stuff so you can render og:* metatags for social sharing urls and SEO, not need to faff with CORS etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the history mode router, you need to render index.html for every get request.
If you add routing for API in express, explicit routing works first, so there is no problem in calling api.